# Testing Openfire with Grinder (BOSH load testing)

Tags: openfire, grinder

I have been trying to test openfire server for Load testing over BOSH but I have been getting the following error after few minutes of run.

1)

```
11/4/11 3:49:33 PM (thread 3 run 0 test 601): Aborted run due to Java exception calling TestRunner

Java exception calling TestRunner

    File "D:\grinder\projects\loadtest\bin\..\tests\..\tests\one2one.py", line 144, in changePresence

    File "D:\grinder\projects\loadtest\bin\..\tests\..\tests\one2one.py", line 208, in __call__

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

2)     I have also been getting 404 Invalid SID errors.

Initially I had set up openfire on Windows 2003 Server but later I set it up on ubuntu 11.10 (RAM 2.0 GiB Intel Core Duo T2400 @ 1.83GHz)

1) Firstly, I ran php curl fetch script to add users to using the userservices plugin to add something around 10,000 uses (during which I got a lot of blank responses , so may be this is related to the problem but I will not focus on this misbehaviour now)

2) But I needed to test this for 400 users so i had the following grinder.properties set:

```
grinder.processes=4

grinder.threads=100

grinder.runs=1



grinder.consoleHost=192.168.1.205

grinder.consolePort=6372



grinder.logDirectory=../logs

grinder.numberOfOldLogs=0

grinder.jvm.arguments=-Dpython.cachedir=../tmp



grinder.script=../tests/one2one.py
```

(this strangely ended up starting only 103 concurrent users)

(I have tried testing this using one agent)

3) I did a bit of a research and found that I could configure openfire for bosh; so i added the following system.properties

```
xmpp.httpbind.client.idle 360

xmpp.httpbind.client.requests.max 400
```

badly need help!!!!! anyone has an insight about how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The "Address already in use" problem is odd.  You may want to try with

```
grinder.processes=1
grinder.threads=400
```

As far as only seeing 103 concurrent users, how long does it take for a single of your grinder runs to execute?  My thinking is the earliest threads the JVM executes are completing before the final threads have a chance to fully initialize and do work.  If you try this:

```
grinder.runs=100
```

You will be more likely to achieve the full level of concurrency you are looking for.

Comment: 1) this worked! and at the same time generates a lot of confusion for me as the same server setting (except that now I use oracle as its db  on OS: ubuntu 11.10) got me embarrassed in front 150 users as most of them were kicked out during a conference chat (the invalid SID problem). I was using Candy web chat client (i.e. BOSH over proxied Apache Win32 ). Some thing tells me this is not the best emulation of the production environment.
Could OS and db cause such problems?

Comment: 2) I have collected some 1667 samples of the test and when i ran it over Grinder Analyzer it gave me a "less than 250 bucket error". Any clue what that is?